# Multiplying list with array as dot product

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I came across a code performing a general dotproduct of a list 'A' with a numpy Array 'B'.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = np.arange(18).reshape(3, len(A))

result = np.dot (B,A)
result2 = np.dot (A,B)
```

`np.dot(A,B)` gives an error: "Value Error: shapes (6,) and (3,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)"

However, `np.dot (B,A)` gives the result [ 70 196 322].

Can you help me understand why `np.dot(B,A)` works but `np.dot(A,B)` does not?

Ideally I would have expected dot product to work only when the number of COLUMNS of my first matrix is the same as the number of ROWS of the second matrix. 
B has 3 rows and 6 columns, A has 1 row 6 columns. So, I would expect both `np.dot(B,A)` and `np.dot(A,B)` to not work.

Comment: It is behaving the way you expect, right? What is the problem here?

Comment: B has 3 rows and 6 columns, A has 1 row 6 columns. since the number of columns of B is not equal to number of rows in A, i will expect np.dot(B,A) to not work.

Comment: N-sized 1-D arrays in numpy are not matrices of size 1xN. You should take a look at the documentation for how `np.dot` behaves when 2nd argument is a 1-D array: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: Did you read the docs?  What they say about 1d arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this operation would never work since `A` and `B` are of different shapes.

However, the reason `np.dot(B, A)` works is because `np.dot` is [vectorized](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). So what is really happening is that `np.dot` is called for all three indexes of B (`B[0]`, `B[1]`, and `B[2]`) and `A`. The returned value of `[70 196 322]` is the result of all three of the `np.dot` calls, combined into one array.

The reason `np.dot(A, B)` gives an error is because a call to `np.dot` with any index of `A` (for example, `np.dot(A[0], B)`), still has an invalid shape.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule for `np.dot(A, B)` is match the last axis of A with the next to the last of B.  In `einsum` notation this is 'ij, jk-> ik' with sum on the shared 'j'.

But `dot` has explicit rules for 1d cases.

(6,) with (6,) produces a scalar (vector inner 'dot' product, `a.b`)

(6,) with (6,3) produces (3,) (shared 6).

(3,6) with (6,) ok also.

But (6,) fails with (3,6) (2nd 6 is in the wrong place).

`matmul` does the same, but talks of adding temporary size 1 dimensions.